# Android ListView won't populate

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to populate my ListView with values from a string array.  There are values in the string array, as I've checked to make sure.  I'm using code that, from what I've seen from previous searches, is correct.  I'm running the app through an Android emulator and have tried creating a new emulator, cleaning the project, and restarting Eclipse.  But still when the app starts up there is no data in the list.

I'm using the Galaxy Nexus emulator running Android 4.2.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView redditView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.redditView);
    String[] redditList = readRedditFeed();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, redditList);

    redditView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public String[] readRedditFeed()
{

    return output;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/redditView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is _very bad_ `catch (Exception e) {}`...  The code probably throws an exception like `NetworkOnMainThreadException` but you will _never_ know. At a minimum you should have `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch-block.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to fix that.  It's fixed now and not throwing any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing data in main thread it may give ANR.

**Use either Thread and handler or AsyncTask.**

After getting parsed result from thread use handler to set adapter in your list
OR
use **AsyncTask** doInbackground() method to receiving and parsing data and onPostExecute()
set adapter in your list.

Answer (score 0):

just use an asyncTask to do the background work without blocking the UI.

```
private LoadingStuffTask task;
private String [] redditList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView redditView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.redditView);
     task = new LoadingStuffTask();
    task.execute("Process started!");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

    private class LoadingStuffTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            redditList=readRedditFeed()
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(
                String... values) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pdia.dismiss();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, redditList);
            redditView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pdia = new ProgressDialog(classificaA.this);
            pdia.setMessage("Doing background..");
            pdia.show();
        }

    }


public String[] readRedditFeed()
{
    ArrayList<String> redditList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try
    {   
        URL url = new URL("http://www.reddit.com/.json");
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));

        String line = "";
        String lines = "";
        while((line = din.readLine()) != null)
            lines += line;

        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(lines).nextValue();
        json = (JSONObject) json.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray) json.getJSONArray("children");

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            json = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            json = (JSONObject) json.getJSONObject("data");
            redditList.add(json.get("title").toString().replaceAll("\"", ""));
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}

    String[] output = new String[redditList.size()];
    redditList.toArray(output);
    return output;
}
}
```